# c++: visual studio 2008/2010 "The breakpoint will not currently be hit." issue

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I have a program which is linked to a static library, in Visual Studio 2008 (win 7 64 bit).
I am encountering the "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." issue, both in Release/Debug mode, for breakpoints in the static library code (breakpoints of the executable code are ok).
I have read and tried the solutions in other SO questions, and nothing helped. My trials include manually deleting all obj and pdb files; restarting VS and the computer; installing Microsoft's hotfix related to that issue; porting the solution to VS 2010.

I would appreciate any other suggestions...

**UPDATE**

After 2 days of futile efforts, including re-creating the solution, the problem disappeared. The step I did just before it fixed itself was to edit the code of another program in the same solution, which loads the same static library, and rebuilding. Got no clue if it is even related to the fact the the problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Strange! Perhaps Advanced Build Settings >> Debug Info was set to "none" ?

Comment: I don't think so, otherwise debugging was always not possible -- this problem just appeared suddenly.